# react native fetch url for expo on web

Tags: react-native, url, fetch

I used this code for connect my android physical device to server and mongo db

```
const Url = "http://192.168.1.2:8080/"
fetch(Url, {
  method: "GET",
  mode: 'no-cors',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  }
})
.then(res=>res.json())
.then(response => console.log(response))
.catch(error => console.log(error));
```

as you can see i can use `192.168.1.2` (IPv4) for connect my android physical device to my computer and server.

but when i use `"http://192.168.1.2:8080/"` or `"http://localhost:8080/"` for my expo on web it doesn't work and get me this console error:

```
GET http://192.168.1.2:8080/ net::ERR_ABORTED 401 (Unauthorized)
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at App.js:34
```

how can solve that? what's Url for expo on web?

Comment: Can you show a fraction of the code you have where this exception is thrown?

Comment: App.js:34 is this line code: .then(res=>res.json()). do you need all function codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after a while and search on net,I found my own solution

there is need change `mode: 'no-cors',` to `mode: 'cors',`

and in nodejs server need add this code:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'application/json,content-type');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    next();
});
```